Identifier of entity must be manually assigned before calling 'persist()'
I'm encountering this error when i try to post through department entity.

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Identifier of entity 'com.ashville.usermanagementsystem.entity.Department' must be manually assigned before calling 'persist()'] with root cause


org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Identifier of entity 'com.ashville.usermanagementsystem.entity.Department' must be manually assigned before calling 'persist()'

this is my entity file.
Department_id is a foreign key in User file.
Department.java
package com.ashville.usermanagementsystem.entity;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.ashville.usermanagementsystem.entity")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer departmentId;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String deptName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OurUsers> users;
    // Constructors
    public Department() {}
    public Department(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    // Getters and Setters
    public Integer getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }
    public void setDepartmentId(Integer departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }
    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }
    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    public List<OurUsers> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(List<OurUsers> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}

Please help to resolve this.

How do you want your keys to be generated?

Which database is being used? AUTO is very vague, I don't really know why it even exists. You will probably want to be using either IDENTITY (H2, MySQL/MariaDB or PostgreSQL) or SEQUENCE (any other database, really). https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers

Also off-topic, but that @EntityScan annotation really does not belong on an entity. The usual place to put it is on the Spring Boot application class, or any class that is a @Configuration class. Just as long as it exists only once within the application.

I want my keys to be autogenerated. I had IDENTITY in place of AUTO before. But it gave me the same error. so I hanged to AUTO. I'm using MS SQL Server DB.

I have changed strategy to IDENTITY and removed EntityScan, and that created a column for me with numbers incrementing. Thank You!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
